# Как можно сократить количество строк в условии на Ruby

Tags: ruby, инспекция-кода

Интересует, как можно и нужно сократить код? 
Что лучше использовать для сокращения?
Нужно сократить именно количество строк в условии.

```
    require "colorize"
    new_name_file = {}

loop do

    puts 
    puts "Файл будем искать по имени(1) расширению(2) имени и расширению(3) выход из программы(4)?"
    print "\n>>>>>> ".magenta
    name_extension = gets.to_i

    if name_extension == 1  # =========== поиск по имени файла =================
        puts "Введите имя файла(test, lesson, ruby....etc.) "
        print "\n>>>>>> ".cyan

        file_name = gets.strip.downcase

        # на каком диске будем искать поставьте букву
        puts "На каком жестком диске будем искать файл(C, D, E, F....e.t.c.): "
        print "\n>>>>>> ".green
        hdd_search = gets.strip.capitalize

        # поиск файла
        contents = Dir.glob("#{hdd_search}:/**/#{file_name}.*")

    elsif name_extension == 2 # ========= поиск по расширению файла =============

        puts "Введите расширение файла(txt, rb, jpg, csv, json) "
        print "\n>>>>>> ".cyan
        file_extension = gets.strip.downcase

        # на каком диске будем искать поставьте букву
        puts "На каком жестком диске будем искать файл(C, D, E, F....e.t.c.): "
        print "\n>>>>>> ".green
        hdd_search = gets.strip.capitalize

        # поиск файла
        # ** - рекурсия, * - условия выборки aka wildcard   
        contents = Dir.glob("#{hdd_search}:/**/*.#{file_extension}") 

    elsif name_extension == 3 # ========= поиск по имени и расширению файла =============

        puts "Введите имя и расширение файла(test.txt, test.rb, test.jpg, test.csv, test.json..etc) "
        print "\n>>>>>> ".cyan
        file_extension_name = gets.strip

        # на каком диске будем искать поставьте букву
        puts "На каком жестком диске будем искать файл(C, D, E, F....e.t.c.): "
        print "\n>>>>>> ".green
        hdd_search = gets.strip.capitalize

        # поиск файла
        # ** - рекурсия, * - условия выборки aka wildcard   
        contents = Dir.glob("#{hdd_search}:/**/#{file_extension_name}") 

    elsif name_extension == 4
        puts "Выход из программы".red
        exit

    end

    contents.each do |txt_name|
        z_name =  File.basename(txt_name)  # имя файла
        path = File.expand_path(txt_name)  # путь к файлу
        new_name_file[z_name] = path       # все в словарь

    end

    new_name_file.each do |k, v|           # вывод словаря
        puts "file : ".cyan + "#{k} " + " path:".cyan +  "#{v}"
    end

end
```

Comment: Пожалуйста прочтите описание метки "инспекция-кода" и последуйте ему.

Comment: Хорошо, что вы хотите сократить код, странно только что вы не видите, что у вас варианты поиска содержат совершенно однотипные последовательности, которые прекрасно унифицируются.

Answer (score 0):

В Руби есть такая конструкция:

```
case name_extension
when 1
  ...
when 2
  ...
when 3
  ..
when 4
  ...
else
  "You gave me #{name_extension} -- I have no idea what to do with that."
end
```